# How to setup apache2 redirect but keep domain name?

Tags: wordpress, redirects, apache2

I run a small community web site where users can each get a free blog. The blog address is always something like http://mydomain.com/blogname

One user have bought his own domain and want to redirect it to his blog. I've managed to setup a 302 redirect but then when he types http//hisdomain.com in the browser he ends up at http://mydomain.com/blogname

He really wants hisdomain.com to still be there. Any idea on how I can set it up so that
http://hisdomain.com/blogname is shown instead?

Environment:
Ubuntu server 10.04
Apache2
Wordpress multi site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If your using WordPress multisite you can use the [Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

> This plugin allows users of a
> WordPress MU site or WordPress 3.0
> network to map their blog/site to
> another domain.
>
> It requires manual installation as one
> file must be copied to wp-content/.
> When upgrading the plugin, remember to
> update domain_mapping.php and
> sunrise.php. Full instructions are on
> the Installation page and are quite
> easy to follow. You should also read
> this page too.
>
> Super administrators must configure
> the plugin in Super Admin->Domain
> Mapping. You must enter the IP or IP
> addresses (comma deliminated) of your
> server on this page. The addresses are
> purely for documentation purposes so
> the user knows what they are (so users
> can set up their DNS correctly). They
> do nothing special in the plugin,
> they're only printed for the user to
> see.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this [WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) might help.  This question might need to go to the [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.